# My app does not launch in my device?

Tags: iphone, crash, provisioning-profile

I am having this problem, for the first time. I am running my app to device with distribution + Ad-Hoc provision profile but I can't able to launch app the first time in device, as I am getting this error continuously:

```
Mar  1 18:07:58 My-iPhon kernel[0] : launchd[276] Builtin profile: container (sandbox)
Mar  1 18:07:58 My-iPhon kernel[0] : launchd[276] Container:             /private/var/mobile/Applications/E142C3CE-F6E0-4C77-ABE8-1B764DA216FE (sandbox)
Mar  1 18:07:58 My-iPhon com.apple.debugserver-189[261] : 1 +0.000000 sec [0105/0303]: error: ::task_for_pid ( target_tport = 0x0103, pid = 276, &task ) => err = 0x00000005 ((os/kern) failure) err = ::task_for_pid ( target_tport = 0x0103, pid = 276, &task ) => err = 0x00000005 ((os/kern) failure) (0x00000005)
Mar  1 18:07:58 My-iPhon mobile_house_arrest[280] : Max open files: 125 
Mar  1 18:07:59 My-iPhon com.apple.debugserver-189[261] : 2 +0.417620 sec [0105/0303]: error: ::task_for_pid ( target_tport = 0x0103, pid = 276, &task ) => err = 0x00000005 ((os/kern) failure) err = ::task_for_pid ( target_tport = 0x0103, pid = 276, &task ) => err = 0x00000005 ((os/kern) failure) (0x00000005)
Mar  1 18:07:59 My-iPhon mobile_house_arrest[281] : Max open files: 125
Mar  1 18:07:59 My-iPhon mobile_house_arrest[282] : Max open files: 125
```

After I launch, the app crashed and in Device Console I got this error:

```
Mar  1 18:11:44 My-iPhon backboardd[52] : BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 50: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
Mar  1 18:11:44 My-iPhon com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.xxx.myApp[0x3077][276]) : (UIKitApplication:com.xxxx.myapp[0x3077]) Exited: Killed: 9
Mar  1 18:11:44 My-iPhon com.apple.debugserver-189[261] : 21 +216.166834 sec [0105/0303]: RNBRunLoopLaunchInferior DNBProcessLaunch() returned error: 'failed to get the task for process 276'
Mar  1 18:11:44 My-iPhon com.apple.debugserver-189[261] : error: failed to launch process (null): failed to get the task for process 276
Mar  1 18:11:44 My-iPhon backboardd[52] : Application 'UIKitApplication:com.xxxxx.myApp[0x3077]' quit with signal 9: Killed: 9
```

However, the third time its running normally!

I have tried it many ways like

1. Recreated my provision profile and also given entitlement.plist for Ad-Hoc distribution
2. I set the scheme's build configuration to debug, so how can i solve this error while running my app first time on my device
3. I restated my device

No matter what I try, I get this error! Can any of you explain this?

Comment: Why would your app be so hungry?

Comment: sorry for my poor english

Comment: no problem! We're here to help, and your post was at least readable.

Comment: i added cordovaLib.xcodeproj and also some of Js file also having

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try using development certificate. It will work fine if you install IPA file in your device.

Use Ad-hoc and distribution provisioning profiles when you are going to upload your app to the app store.